# download report as pdf using servlet

Tags: servlets, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I have the pdf file location and pdf file in my POJO class. I want to download thee pdf using servlet. Please tell me some ways to get it done.
 File Location=/tmp/SWBC_444Thu May 03 20:01:07 IST 20124366242221752147545.pdf
Using this file location i want to prompt user to download the file as pdf.

Here is my code.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
  OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream(); 
  response.setContentLength((int)filePath.length());
  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
  int size = fileInputStream.available();
  byte[] content = new byte[size];
  int bytesRead;
  while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(content)) != -1)   
  {  
   responseOutputStream.write(content, 0, bytesRead);  
  }
  responseOutputStream.flush();
  fileInputStream.close();
  responseOutputStream.close();
```

. I read and generate the file but when open the file its empty.

Thanking you..!

Comment: You can view this posts: [JasperReports: Calling report from servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399507/jasperreports-calling-report-from-servlet) & [Report download not prompting user to save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085049/report-download-not-prompting-user-to-save). The search on SO works great ;)

Comment: File file = new File(filePath);

      ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
      ;
      BufferedInputStream bufferIput = null;
      FileInputStream fileInputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
      bufferIput = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
      byte[] bBuffer = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
      int nBytes = -1;
      while ((nBytes = bufferIput.read(bBuffer, 0, bBuffer.length))
        != -1)
      {
        servletOutputStream.write(bBuffer, 0, nBytes);
      }   Problem solved. You can use this code to read an pdf file and download

Comment: You can post the solution as the answer to help others

Answer (score 0):

httpservletresponse.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + title + ".pdf\""); should do

Comment: i did that..I mean its a basic thing for pdf. Anyway,Now i read the pdf file from specified file location and the pdf file is generated but when i open the file ,it doesnt display anything,File